# Car stalls/dies suddenly while driving and is not starting again

Tags: engine, electrical, starting, stall, tata

I own a Indian Make TATA INDICA Ev2 (CR4) Turbo Engine car. I did rebore recently and the mileage was 130,000 KMs. After rebore first service of 3000 km is successfully completed and now I'm facing a problem with sudden stall of the engine while driving. Immediately tried to start the engine but no crank sound or anything (completely dead). Later after some time I tried and the engine cranks and starts successfully! What would be the problem?

Engine oil is on good level, radiator water is on good level, I changed the starter solenoid. Can't identify what causes this problem!

Comment: How is your thermostat? Also check the ECM fuse.

Comment: It sounds like you have an intermittent ground (earth) issue. Check the ground where it meets the body and ensure you have a good connection (no corrosion/tight connection). Also, check your other ground straps as well. Losing the ground to the PCM can cause issues like you are suggesting.

Comment: Do the dash lights work correctly even when it doesn't start?

Comment: @paulster2 :thanks for the reply ! let me check the ground to the engine and ill let you know the feedback in few hours.

Comment: @HandyHowie : everything indication is fine in the dashboard. but now i found an temporary solution for it , if the engine stalls and did not crank after it ! i just fix the car to third gear and i tried moving the car till the engine get a push ,then in few seconds i sat inside the car and tried to start the car then the engine works ! .... later after few kms/miles drive again the engine stalls :(

Comment: @Anarach : Thank you ! Thermostat is fine ! let me check the ECM fuse and revert you back

Comment: It is sounding like a ground problem like @paulster2 said.

Comment: everything i had checked friends.... but still the problem didn't solve

Comment: All - this is a good question.  OP is responding and checking various suspected issues.

Comment: There are some good comments here that should be written up as answers. It is okay to amend the answer as information develops. Remember, the next person with this problem won't be reading all the chatty comments. They'll be looking for an answer.

Comment: When the starter starts working again does the car always start?

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is almost certainly an electrical problem (or two). It sounds like two things are happening and they are quite likely related:

1. Something is causing the engine to shutdown (your may find [What can cause a gasoline engine to suddenly & mysteriously stop](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/32984/what-can-cause-a-gasoline-engine-to-suddenly-mysteriously-stop-non-catastroph) helpful for thinking about what could be happening).
2. Something is causing the starter motor not to run, or perhaps something is inhibiting the starter solenoid from pulling in.

Since these things happen together, I'd start by looking for a common element. Some things to check would be:

- Grounds – especially if any of them were disconnected in the process of doing the rebore. Was the engine taken out of the car? If it was the grounds to the block should be double checked.
- Common points in the circuits that support the engine (ignition, fuel delivery, ECU) and that control the starter.
- If you can check, see if you see a start signal to the starter solenoid when you try to start after the car shuts down – this will help you determine the cause. Measure between the small terminal on the solenoid and the battery to eliminate the ground as the possible problem.
- Aiso double check that the car appears to have been put back together correctly – for example if a heat shield was left off from around the turbo it could cause nearby electrical components to malfunction (perhaps there is a self-resetting circuit breaker that is overheating and "mistaking" a hot environment for excessive current).

In general, I think it is more likely that there would be one common cause for the two problems than that that two, related, problems have suddenly cropped up, but if the engine was pulled to do the rebore it is possible that there are multiple issues and they just happen to be related. But, as a starting point, I'd be looking at common points in the circuits.

Answer (score -2):

The issue is most definitely electrical. I'd suggest take it to the nearest Tata authorized service centre and get it checked. It is not practical to diagnose electrical issue yourself.

Comment: We're all about trying to diagnose issues ourselves here… Diagnosing many electrical problems just requires some pretty basic tools and an understanding of the principles involved.

Comment: It has been my personal experience that electrical issues that an experienced hand works a lot faster and more efficiently.  I am all for DIY, but I think it to be more practical to let someone with experience the electrical and hover over him while he handles it to learn yourself.

With automotive electricals even a circuit diagram may not be able to ease the situation. Again, it's my 2 cents (and apparently, not popular).