# Can overfilling a gas tank damage a fuel pump?

Tags: engine, troubleshooting, overheating, fuel-tank

I was driving a car with an overly full gas tank. After about 20min of driving, I pulled into a parking lot and the engine died. After waiting about 15min with the hood open (I thought it might be a heat issue as it was hot out), the car started fine.

I read [What can cause a gasoline engine to suddenly & mysteriously stop](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/32989/29391), and it wasn't mentioned. As this has never happened before, I was wondering if it was connected to overfilling the tank.

Comment: No but it can damage the vapor storage system.

Comment: I read about that. Would this cause the car to shut off randomly?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Moab stated, overfilling the gas tank will not cause an issue with the fuel pump. In fact, the fuel pump likes there to be fuel in the tank. If there's not enough fuel, you can overheat the fuel pump ... but no way to cause it issues with too much gas.